# how to check 2 columns values are match using laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

Iam trying to check 2 columns  values are match or not?
i have 1 db table Classes(id,cls,divn)
 im select class from the list box.using tag. and also enter division from the list box.using tag..
if select(eg: class-1 and division -A )if its is already in database ,givean alert msg..it is already taken other wise save into database.
im using controller.php code is

```
try
{
    $clss = Input::get('cls');
    $divn = Input::get('divn');
    $cs = ForumClass::where('cls', '=', $clss && 'divn', '=', $divn );

    if((empty($cs)))
    {
        throw new  \Exception("Class not found");              
    }

    return Redirect::route('getclasses')
       ->with('success','Its Already taken');    
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{  
    ForumClass::create([
       'cls'=>Input::get('cls').'-'.Input::get('divn'),
    ]); 

    return Redirect::route('classes')
         ->with('fail','classes submited');        
}
```

now my problem is ..this code is not work.`$cs = ForumClass::where('cls', '=', $clss && 'divn', '=', $divn );` 
if any selected class-1 and division-A contain  alert "Its Already taken"
its true,,,

but class-8 and division-D is ot in database but its also give the same alert "Its Already taken".

my database

id     cls      divn

1       1        A

2       5        C

4      10        A

5       4        G
how to check 2 columns values are already exits or not in laravel 4.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are part way there, do it like so;

```
$cs = ForumClass::where('cls', $clss)->where('divn', $divn )->first();
```

If you don't need to use the record, instead use `->exists()` method.

If there is one this will return the model, if not it will return `null`. Without using the `->first()` or `->get()` method your query will not be executed.

Comment: Note that you can also use `exists()` instead of `first()` if you don't need the actual record.

Comment: iam using   this code $cs = ForumClass::where('cls', $clss)->where('divn', $divn )->first();...its work ...............thank you